Api request to disable 2fa in the status pending django
the request freezes in the 2fa disable handle. I can't figure out why. Here is my code. I use pyotp
class DisableOTPAPIView(APIView):
    serializer_class = IdSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = IdSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user_id = serializer.validated_data['id']
        if not User.objects.filter(id=user_id).exists():
            raise NotFound('Пользователь не найден.')
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        user.otp_verified = False
        user.otp_base32 = None
        user.otp_auth_url = None
        user.save()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

serializer
class IdSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()

model
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex=r'^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$')],
        unique=True,
        verbose_name='email')
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                   verbose_name='администратор')
    telegram = models.CharField(
        verbose_name='telegram',
        max_length=50,
        unique=True,
        validators=[RegexValidator(
            regex=r'@[a-zA-Z0-9_]{5,32}$'
        )])
    role = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_MODELS, max_length=20,
                            blank=True,
                            verbose_name='poль')
    is_verify = models.BooleanField(default=False,
                                    verbose_name='верифицирован')
    free_cards = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Кол-во бесплатных карт')
    otp_verified = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    otp_base32 = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    otp_auth_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

I will glad everything help. Advance thanks
Everything works fast locally, but when uploading to the server, this particular request hangs.I can't tell you the server data. I need to make sure that the problem is not in the code.
